# Can't do a basic request on Postman

Tags: reactjs, postman, react-fullstack

I am following a full-stack react course, and I am using Postman for the first time. I have tried several times to do a GET request, but I keep getting the same error:

`Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http:localhost Request Headers User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.32.2 Accept: */* Host: http:localhost:8000 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br Connection: keep-alive`

I am not sure what the error means or how to solve it.

I was expecting to get the string 'hello' in the response: instead I got this error.

Comment: Good Luck with your learning. Fix the host path to be http://localhost:8000. Http slash slash

Comment: try localhost:8000